# Получить числовые значения из множества entries в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

После первоначального ввода количества ролей,
автоматически делается столько entry, сколько собственно было введено ролей.
В появившиеся entry ввожу данные по каждому из ролей.
Вопрос: как эти данные из всех entry поместить в один список (my_entries)?

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.resizable(width=False, height=True)
window.title('Split file')


label = tk.Label(
                window, text='Введите количество ролей: '
                ).grid(row=0, column=0)

rols_num = tk.Entry(window)
rols_num.grid(row=0, column=1)

my_entries = []

def ok_button():
   
    global entry_mult
    for i in range(int(rols_num.get())):
        label_mult = tk.Label(window, text=f'Количество кодов в роле № {i+1}').grid(row=i+1, column=0)
        entry_mult = tk.Entry(window)
        entry_mult.grid(row=i+1, column=1)

button_ok = tk.Button(
window, text='Ввести количество ролей',command=ok_button).grid(row=0, column=2)
    

def write_to_list():
    for i in entry_mult:
        my_entries.append(i.get())

button_apply_values = tk.Button(
window, text='Записать значения', command=write_to_list).grid(row=5, column=2)


window.mainloop()
print (my_entries)
```

Comment: Сложите entry_mult в список. Сейчас это один элемент

Comment: Спасибо, с этим советом разобрался!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.resizable(width=False, height=True)
window.title('Split file')


label = tk.Label(
window, text='Введите количество ролей: ').grid(row=0, column=0)

rols_num = tk.Entry(window)
rols_num.grid(row=0, column=1)

my_entries = []
helplist =[]

def ok_button():
    global entry_mult
    for i in range(int(rols_num.get())):
        label_mult = tk.Label(window, text=f'Количество кодов в роле № {i+1}').grid(row=i+1, column=0)
        entry_mult = tk.Entry(window)
        entry_mult.grid(row=i+1, column=1)
        helplist.append(entry_mult)

button_ok = tk.Button(
window, text='Ввести количество ролей',command=ok_button).grid(row=0, column=2)

def write_values():
    for entries in helplist:
        my_entries.append(entries.get())
 
button_apply_values = tk.Button(
window, text='Записать значения', command=write_values).grid(row=5, column=2)  


window.mainloop()
```